# What does the subscript of atomic orbital mean?

Tags: electronic-configuration, quantum-chemistry

As everyone knows, the atomic orbital can be classified as $s, p_z, p_x, p_y, d_{z^2},d_{xz},d_{yz},d_{xy},d_{x^2-y^2}$ and so on. I want to know the meaning of $z^2,x^2-y^2$ and so on. Maybe this is a fundamental question, but I'm not familiar with chemistry.

---

I have some ideas about this:

1. For example, we consider the $p$ orbital: $p_z$ is symmetric about $z$ axis; $p_x$ is symmetric about $x$ axis; $p_y$ is symmetric about $y$ axis. But what's the meaning of $z^2$ or $x^2 -y^2$?
2. We consider the symmetry of atomic orbital with group theory. The change of orbital under the symmetry operation is the same as the orbital subscript.

Comment: I have deleted my post, if I get correct relevance I will repost. But, you can notice that d_xy is symmetric about x+y axis.

Comment: @GODPARTICLE Do you mean x+y axis is x=y axis?

Comment: Yes. The vector x+y will be $45^0$ with respect to both x and y axis.

Comment: But it does not work for all （╯_╰）

Comment: It does for all xy, yz, zx involved subscripts.

Comment: I do agree that it doesn't work for other subscripts.

Comment: @GODPARTICLE In fact, I think you are in the wrong way. For example, $d_{xy}$ has 3 symmetry axes(if you konw about the point group, the axis should be called $C_2$ exactly).

Comment: ): May be, but good question. I have something to learn from any of the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

For each [azimutal quantum number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_number) $l$, the [magnetic quantum number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_number) $m$ ranges from $-l$ to $+l$. Those give you the number of atomic orbitals "subsripts" you should obtain.
Those are then expressed using [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics). If you look at the [table of spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics) at the $l=1$, you will find that they contain the cartesian axes as $x-y$, $z$ and $x+y$. Therefore it is advisable to form the linear combination out of them, so you get $x$, $y$, $z$. If you go to higher angular momentum, things get more complicated, but there is some tradition what linear combinations to use.

To answer your second question, all this formulas are not some inevitable result you obtain by juggling the numbers. Contrary, it is carefully crafted in a way that the formulas are so simple.

Comment: 1)What do you mean "you will find that they contain the cartesian axes as $x−y$, $z$ and $x+y$."? 2)I want know why the subscripts are written as $z$, $z^2$, $x^2-y^2$ and so on respectively. 3)You say "it is carefully crafted in a way that the formulas are so simple.", and I'm not clear about "the formulas". Can you explain it more specificly?

Comment: 1. Please have a careful look at the table of spherical harmonics at l=1, i.e. p-orbitals in cartesian coordinates and try to understand, what I have written.

Comment: I know how to combine spherical to obtain $p_x$, $p_y$...But I do not know why choose x, y, z and so on as subscripts.

Comment: The orientation of the orbitals. For $p$, one is oriented in the x direction one is oriented in the y direction and one is one the z direction.

Comment: Bach: We chose the orientation for immense convenience. It is great, if you expand some equation and magically 95% of the terms disappear just because you have chosen good coordinate system.
And the labels $p_x$,... just show, which axes and in which power appear in the spherical harmonic expression.

Comment: @user2612743 What about $d_{x^2-y^2}$, $d_{z^2}$ and so on?

Comment: @ssavec I want to know how the labels show which axes and in which power appear in the spherical harmonic expression.

Comment: @Bach: have you followed the simpler example for p-orbitals? And plotted the spherical harmonics in 3D? And formed linear combinations of them?

Comment: @ssavec You can explain directly. For example, you explain how $d_{x^2−y^2}$ show which axes and in which power appear in the spherical harmonic expression.

Comment: @Bach: I still do not get your point. For example, the $d_{z^2}$ obviously contains z-axis in the power of 2 and is obtained as linear combination: $Y_2^{-2}+Y_2^{+2}+2Y_2^0$ (up to prefactor). 
If the problem is in visualization, than you have to use visualization program. At least I am not able to see how the axis in the expression affect the shape of function without producing a graph.

Comment: I mean why choose $z^2$ as the subscript? Dose $z^2$ mean someting?

Comment: @Bach: I still do not understand. It means it is there in the equation. And this linear combination was chosen to make subsequent calculations much simpler. What type of meaning it should have?

Comment: I don't know the subscript's meaning, so I ask this question. I think the subscript is not chosen at random just for definition. For example, when we consider the symmetry of atomic orbital, the subscript make some coincidence.

Comment: As you noted, the symmetry is also an important concept, as it governs the magnetic quantum number, so $p_z$ has $m=0$ and the remaining $p_x$ and $p_y$ have $m=\pm 1$. So it is definitely not random. But for $l>1$, so d and higher angular momentum, the exact composition is IMHO not straightforward, but chosen under some constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but OP seemed unhappy with any of the answers and this is a great question I had for years as a chemistry student, suffering what I felt were vague explanations when I just wanted a precise formula.  I wanted to see that subscript as part of the polynomial in the wavefunction.  After all that time, here's my answer:

The orbitals have the same symmetry as the function $\psi(x,y,z) = $ "subscript".

p-orbitals $p_x$, $p_y$, and $p_z$ have the same symmetry as $\psi = x$, $\psi = y$, and $\psi = z$. They have nodes where that function is 0, and they flip sign where that function does, just dampened by a decreasing exponential $e^{-r}$, rather than going off to infinity. Basically $\psi = xe^{-r}$ (Not exactly the solution but very close).

d-orbitals have same symmetry as $\psi = xy$, $\psi = yz$, $\psi = xz$, $\psi = x^2-y²$, ... and the tricky one, $z²$ is short for $z² - (x² + y²)$, which gives you conical nodes and a sign flip with the horizontal radius $\sqrt{x^2 + y²} > z$.

The same holds true for the f-orbitals, with again one of them being a short-hand.  Slightly annoying, I know, but once someone TELLS you, it's ok.

Hope that helps.